# Is there a project for annotating e-books?

Tags: historical-context

There are a number of projects collecting out of copyright literary works and making them available for download, e.g. [Project Gutenberg](https://www.gutenberg.org/) and [Bibebook](https://www.bibebook.com/).

Many of these books would benefit from annotation (e.g. footnotes clarifying details that would have been obvious to contemporary readers, but which would be obscure to most people nowadays).

Is there an internet project, somewhat akin to [Wikipedia](https://wikipedia.org) where readers can collaborate to provide annotations and explanations to classic texts?

Comment: Have you looked into Archive.org? I am not well-versed in all that they do, but they do extensive work in preservation and cataloguing of all types of media from all over the world.

Comment: @GWarner I have looked at dozens of books on Archive.org. Books are scanned and made available there in several formats, but annotating them appears to be outside the site's scope. it would also require scholarly knowledge and you're not likely to find academics who want to give their time to such a project.

Comment: @Tsundoku, given the success of crowd-sourced knowledge sites (e.g. Wikipedia, Stack Exchange) I don't see why providing wiki-like annotation requires extraordinary knowledge or dedication.  Obviously, some types of annotation would require more specialist knowledge, but e.g. identifying once-famous but now obscure individuals is something that many of us could do quite easily.